# GPU performance dilemma - multiple draw calls with separate vertex buffers vs. single draw call with a common vertex buffer

Tags: c++, gpu, directx, metal

I need to render a scene consisting of many simple objects. Some objects change rarely and have a fixed number of triangles, others change more frequently, and some may also change their number of triangles.

I'm facing a dilemma:

I can create a vertex buffer for each object. In this case I will only send the vertex buffers of the objects that have changed in each frame, and save bandwidth on the rest of objects. This approach is also easier to maintain. However, I will have as many draw calls as there are objects.

Or alternatively, I can create a big single vertex buffer shared by all objects. On change, I will update parts of the vertex buffer on CPU (a little harder to implement) and then send the entire buffer to GPU. This will result in more bandwidth (unchanged vertexes will be sent unnecessarily) but I get a single draw call.

What will be more performant and what is the recommended common practice?

Also is there a middle ground that I'm missing, that would allow me to both avoid sending unchanged data and yet avoid numerous draw calls?

I'm interested in a solution for both Metal and DirectX.

Comment: Have you looked into sending partial updates instead?

Comment: Yes, but I suspect that a bunch of partial updates may not be faster than sending a single buffer at once. Besides, I've had problems with syncing - I updated a shared buffer and committed it to the GPU, then changed the buffer on the CPU for the next frame, and GPU sometimes rendered a garbled old/new frame instead of the old frame.

Comment: updates tend to be scheduled per "page" of some fixed size, so that should be a wash. Your other problem is probably related to the lack of memory barrier or so.

Comment: Can you sort the objects depending on their staticity? Maybe this way you can just make two calls. One for static, one for dynamic.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something like this. I group rarely changed objects and start a new group whenever there is a frequently changed object. This partially solves the problem (the rarely changed objects still change sometimes, so their buffer needs to be sent). I just wondered if there was a more elegant solution that I'm missing.